# Objects are being saved only to the Parse Server and not to the MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, parse-platform

I have an AWS EC2 Instance running Ubuntu. I have installed Parse Server on it and it runs on localhost.

I've added a new object to the server using this command:

```
$ curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

After I've added this sample object, I used this command in order to get that object back:

```
$ curl -X GET \
   -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
   http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore/2ntvSpRGIK
```

And I got this output, which means that it is on the database:

```
{
  "objectId": "2ntvSpRGIK",
  "score": 1337,
  "playerName": "Sean Plott",
  "cheatMode": false,
  "updatedAt": "2016-03-11T23:51:48.050Z",
  "createdAt": "2016-03-11T23:51:48.050Z"
}
```

But for some reason, the class GameScore isn't being shown not on the Parse dashboard and not on my migrated database on MongoDB. The MongoDB is on the same server as the Parse Server. 
Is it okay or there is a problem?

Comment: Parse server doesnt use any other storage than the mongoDB so it has to be there, mongoDB can have more databases so you can check that... I recommend [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: I followed this tutorial from the beginning.

Comment: Then login is pm2 user and run "pm2 logs" command and share it here... On 95% it will tell you what is wrong

Comment: sorry I meant parse user -- sudo su parse and then run pm2 logs

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the database Uri

```
--databaseURI <DatabaseURI>
```